# drop column with empty name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with empty column name `df.info()`:

```
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------           --------------  ----- 
 0   Timestamp        11586 non-null  object
 1   Email address    11586 non-null  object
 2                    11586 non-null  object
 3   Score            11586 non-null  object
 4   ID               11586 non-null  object
 5   variable         11586 non-null  object
 6   Answer           11586 non-null  object
```

It can also be at different column index such as :

```
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------           --------------  ----- 
 0   Timestamp        11586 non-null  object
 1   Email address    11586 non-null  object
 2   Score            11586 non-null  object
 3                    11586 non-null  object
 4   ID               11586 non-null  object
 5   variable         11586 non-null  object
 6   Answer           11586 non-null  object
```

How can I drop the empty column name regardless the position?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: @Aelius  OP explicitly mentions that the table is the output of `df.info()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
df = df[[x for x in df.columns if len(x)>=1]]
```

This approach does not care in which index the empty name is, it just takes every column that has a length of at least 1 or more.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you want to drop column 3

```
columns_list = [ 3 ] # index numbers of columns you want to delete
df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[columns_list])
```